# Why result of "RegexOptions.RightToLeft" is not the same as LeftToRight?

Tags: c#, .net

My string ==>    a="b*cde-fg, h" i="jkl.mn" opqrs="tu/vw" x="yz"

The result I want ==>>    b*cde-fg, h

My pattern ==>>    a="(.+?)\"

If I use RegexOptions as LeftToRight (Normal mode) It will give a result ==>>    b*cde-fg, h

But if I use RegexOptions as RightToLeft It will give a result ==>>    b*cde-fg, h" i="jkl.mn" opqrs="tu/vw" x="yz

What should I do to make the results of RightToLeft similar to LeftToRight?

Comment: Is there a reason you want to use RightToLeft?

Comment: Inside the full string  will have a sub string that I want. If I'm searching from left to right, it would be very difficult to find, because there are many similar string. But I know the answer I want to stay ahead of the unique string.

Comment: Have you considered changing your regex. For instance not allowing embedded `"`?

Answer (score 2):

It is returning the correct result, RightToLeft means walking the Regex from right to left.

When you use a non-greedy binding you are not saying "give me the shortest string that matches" you are saying "once you have a match stop processing".

It starts by consuming the `"` and then any number of characters finally a `a="` the first time this matches is the beginning of the string.